# jQuery: Calling append() from within success function

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use jQuery to get the html contents of another page on the server and display it on the current page. Using an alert() function i can see the exact html that needs to be written, however, when i attempt to append, it causes some sort of error, and nothing is displayed at all when i load the page. I also tried to store the html to a variable and use document.write() to add it to the page, but found that the variable was empty... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var totalPages = $("#hidden_navinfo .totalpages").text();
   var currentPage = $("#hidden_navinfo .startpage").text();
   var next = "";
   for ( var i = 1, len = totalPages; i < len; i++)
   {
        var count = i+1;
        //$("#posts").load("/page/ .page");
        $.get(("/page/" + count), function(data) {
            var begin = data.indexOf("<!--BEGIN POST DATA-->")+22;
            var end = data.indexOf("<!--END POST DATA-->");
            next = data.substring(begin, end);
            alert(next); //displays the correct html
            $(".posts").append(next); //Causes nothing to be displayed
        });
        alert(next); //returns null
    }
</script>
```

As far as im aware, this should add the text stored in "next" to the div of class="posts". The script is placed directly after this div.

What am i doing wrong?

(The html that is being extracted can be found here: http://www.trivialreviews.com/ext/sample.html)
(The page the script is called from can be found here: http://fuckmodernity.tumblr.com/tagged/series1/)

Comment: can you post the html that is correctly displayed in your alert? maybe the problem is there...

Comment: yes it can be found in the link above.

Comment: There is no element with the class `posts`

Comment: Or is that link only showing html that is being posted back? If that is the case, can you please post the html of your page? Or at least the relevant parts...

Comment: that link contains the html that is supposed to be inserted into the div class="posts", its not the document that is calling it.

Comment: i've added a link to the calling page

Comment: @Madison I can't see the `<!--BEGIN POST DATA-->` text anywhere in the source. Also, a lot of that page is generated via JavaScript which isn't going to work in your `append()` call

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I can think of is that the document hasn't completely loaded and the `$('.posts')` call is returning an empty object.

Try wrapping your script in the document ready handler, eg

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // your script
});
```

Also, I'd recommend appending the new content into a single element, identified by ID. You may have multiple elements with `class="posts"` which will cause confusion.

```
$('#ajax-content-div').append(next);
```

Another hint, your JavaScript console (usually Ctrl+Shift+J) is much better for debugging than issuing alerts

```
console.log(next);
```

Comment: no luck with that. i should add that when i replace the "next" variable with a simple html string like "<p>test</p>", then the append works properly, which does mean it must be a problem with the html... however the html seems to be formatted properly because it loads correctly on its own page.

Comment: Also, even when the html is inserted into a different div with display set to 'none', the screen still shows up blank...